# Facebook API page published posts "total_count" defaulting to 25 no matter how far back I set the "since" parameter

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
from pyfacebook import GraphAPI
api = GraphAPI(access_token="{access-token}")
api.get_object('{page-id}/published_posts', summary='total_count', since='2011-11-22', limit='0')
```

This is my code, when I have the 'since' parameter set to 2021-11-22, the total_count is at 10, when I keep incrementing it back it keeps increasing then at a certain point it seems to 'max out' at 25.

```
{'data': [], 'summary': {'total_count': 25}}
```

What's going on?

I'd like to retrieve the total number of posts made by a page I'm an admin of. The reason is I scraped all posts on that page, and they were *above* the so-called '600 post' per year limit. For my own sanity check, I'd like to make sure there's no bug in my code by checking that I *am* in fact getting all posts or not.

So I'd like to get an 'official' count of all published posts by this page I'm an admin of.

How can I do that?

I should mention: my app is in development mode and I don't have plans of making it public. Could this be a cause?